# How to change full screen mode during play video

Tags: android, multimedia

Now I am make video player. and try to make video screen size change.

I find

```
MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener mSizeChangedListener =
    new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
```

but this is callback function. not direct call function.

How to change video screen size?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this demo on the android site, look at the method `startVideoPlayback`

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the screen size by calling SetFixedSize() on your SurfaceHolder:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html